# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm saving up some data using python as a CSV file while trying to convert the string(numeric icons) to int.

```
style_tag = soup.select('style')
icons = (str(style_tag[1]).split("."))
mp = {}
for e in icons:
if "icon-" in e:
if "content" in e:
mp[e.split("{")[0].split(":")[0]] = (int(e.split('"')[1][-2:])) - 1
```

The above lines shows the error

```
mp[e.split("{")[0].split(":")[0]] = (int(e.split('"')[1][-2:])) - 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

Comment: Your code is trying to convert `'-'` string to integer format, that's why this error !

Comment: check `e.split('"')[1][-2:]` if it is integer or not ?

Comment: yes when i print(e.split('"')[1][-2]) the resultant outcome is 01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11

Comment: any possibility to ignore '-'

Answer (score 1):

The problem come from

```py
int(e.split('"')[1][-2:])
```

The result of the expressions that you try to convert in int is the character '-' and python cant interpret this as a int. 
The problem is just that you didn't select the right part of ur data with

```py
e.split('"')[1][-2:]
```

To help you more we will need a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of this single line :

```
mp[e.split("{")[0].split(":")[0]] = (int(e.split('"')[1][-2:])) - 1
```

Try this :

```
key_ = e.split("{")[0].split(":")[0]
val_ = e.split('"')[1][-2:]
try:
    val_int = int(val_) - 1
    mp[key_] = val_int
except Exception:
    pass
```

Comment: @Gaurav With `try-except` block you shouldn't be getting the same error. If you are still getting `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:` this might be coming from some other lines where you're trying to convert non-int type string to integer form. Can you print `val_` ?

Comment: yes when i print the resultant outcome is 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11

Comment: val_ = e.split('"')[1][-2:]
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @Gaurav The `IndentationError` has nothing to do with `ValueError`. Check whether the code is properly indented and all the indents are spaces.